# QNetworkReply finished signal slot not emitting on Windows 10

Tags: qt, windows-10, qt4, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have the following code to get the response of the url using QNetworkAccessManager and using QNetworkReply for getting the response code. I am getting the onReplyfinished()slot properly while testing this in windows 8. I am not getting the onReplyfinished() while using the application in Windows 10.

```
 NetManager.h :

class NetManager:public QNetworkAccessManager
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public:

    NetManager(QObject* inParent = 0);

    ~NetManager();

  public slots:

     void onReplyfinished();

  private:

      QNetworkAccessManager *AManager;

      QNetworkReply *NReply;
      QString urlStr;
};

 NetManager.cpp :

 NetManager::NetManager( QObject* inParent ) : QNetworkAccessManager( 
 inParent )
{

   AManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

   urlStr= "https://sampleurl.com/";

   qDebug() << urlStr;

     QUrl url(urlStr);

    QNetworkRequest NetRequest((url));

    NReply= AManager->get(NetRequest);

    connect(NReply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onReplyfinished()));

 }

 void NetManager::onReplyfinished()

 {
    qDebug () << "in getting response";
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to connect to some of the other [signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#signals) to find out which are being emitted.  Chances are an error is occurring somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 0):

do not forget to add 
`QT  += network` in .pro file

and also if you are receiving ssl problems do not forget to copy `libcrypto`and  `libssl`into your project directory